# Python 3, converting string to bytestring

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, xor

I'm trying to create a function that will XOR two bytes in python 3. This works, and I get a string that looks like a bytes out of it, but it says it isn't bytes (if I print it it doesn't have the b infront of it, and if I try to concat it with bytes it will say you can't concat str and bytes.)

When I then try to convert it back into bytes, it for some reason doubles in length. Exemplified by the below code. It doesn't matter if I use .encode() or bytes(), it still increases in length. Please help me, I want it to return bytes out :)

```
def by_xor(x, y):
    l = len(y)
    s = ""
    for i in range(len(x)):
        s += chr(x[i] ^ y[i % l])
    return s

a = b'random text'
b = b'\xd2\xf1\x83\x99'

x = by_xor(a, b)
print(x)
print(len(x))

x = x.encode()
print(x)
print(len(x))
```

Comment: Did you try `bytes(x[i] ^ y[i % l] for i in range(len(x)))` ?

Comment: That works, thanks a lot.

Why does that work when mine doesn't?